# command in terminal and in script have different action

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file and I need to use `sed` to process it.

Here is my command: `sed -i -e '/.*tour\.html\|.*Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg/!d'`.

Now if I execute this command from the terminal, for example, `sed -i -e '/.*tour\.html\|.*Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg/!d' myfile.txt`, it works well. But if I write a bash script with the same command, it will delete all lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -e '/.*tour\.html\|.*Thumb[^\/]*\.jpg/!d' "$1"
```

This script will delete all lines in file.

My PC is Mac OS.

Comment: Show the output of `sed --version` and `sed --help` (the part on -i) in both cases.

Comment: @Yunnosch  I execute `sed --version` in terminal and I got some info, whereas I write `sed --version` in the script and execute this script, I got an error: `sed: illegal option -- -`. So It means that I have two kinds of `sed`?

Comment: ^^ Yes, you probably have 2 copies of `sed` installed. And based on your `PATH` variable, `bash` is picking different ones in 2 cases. Check output of `which sed` in both the cases.

Comment: That's why I learned perl because with sed depending on version the regex syntax will be different

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was this question downvoted?

Comment: You found out that you have two different seds (assuming your test was correct). Now look through `--help` for differences. I bet on syntax for `-i` option, it might require an extension in one case and allow it optionally in the other.

Comment: @Yunnosch  can you answer this question so that I can accept it?

Comment: My pleasure. However, could you provide the version details and the help texts on `-i` ? I think it would be an improvement of the detail level of the answer and make for a better Q/A pair. Feel free to replace my last answer paragraph by that information.

Comment: @Yunnosch  I think your answer is good enough. In fact my PC is Mac OS, and Mac has its own `sed`. To use the Linux `sed`, I download another `sed`, named `gsed`. So it means that `gsed` and `sed` of Mac mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand getting both sed instances output of `sed --help` and `sed --version` showed that you have actually two different sed versions reacting to the two different ways of execuing your code.

Sed is a little inconsistent concerning the syntax, especially when it comes to commandline options.

For example, I know of an important difference for the `-i` switch, which in some Mac versions **requires** a file extension for backups being given explicitly. Others allow one **optionally**. This difference could explain why somethign involving a `-i` without backup extension works in one case and fails in another.

Anishsane suggested that different "PATH" variables could in turn be part of the mechanism to have two different sed versions executed.

I invite OP to edit the output of `--help` and `--version` (where possible, there should be a way to get the version out of both sed instances) here into this answer. I do not have those details actually. Which makes this answer seem a little "guessing".